# Use CapsLock/FnLock LED as HDD LED

Tags: keyboard, hard-drive

My Samsung np370r4v notebook doesn't come with a built-in HDD indicator LED.

My **Fn-Lock** or **Caps-Lock** LEDs are pretty much unused (I don't really need them). Is there any way to make either of them to work as a **HDD LED** indicator?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ledcontrol`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/ledcontrol.1.html) for that precise purpose.

You might be interested by [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/362694/use-caps-lock-led-as-hdd-led-or-custom-indicator) as well.